# PHP - How to get Shell errors echoed out to screen

Tags: php, shell, ffmpeg, shell-exec

I am in the process of using `shell_exec()` for the first time. I am trying to convert some video files on my server using the ffmpeg shell script.

When I the below code in the browser, it returns NULL:

```
var_dump(shell_exec("ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/sitedomain/httpdocs/tmp/ebev1177.mp4"));
```

However when I run the equivalent code in my terminal:

`> ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/sitedomain/httpdocs/tmp/ebev1177.mp4`

I get back a whole load of useful information which ends in an error `"At least one output file must be specified"`

Why is this info not being passed back to my PHP script so I can echo it out?

Comment: You could try to append `2>&1` at the end of the command to redirect the error message to the standard output

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The error data is output from the target program's `STDERR` stream. You can get access to the error data through the normal returned string from `shell_exec()` by appending `2>&1` to the command, which will redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, the stream that you are currently seeing:

```
var_dump(shell_exec("ffmpeg -i /var/www/html/sitedomain/httpdocs/tmp/ebev1177.mp4 2>&1"));
```

You may also want to take a look at [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/proc-open) which will allow you to get access to `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` as three individual streams, which can afford much finer grained control over the target program and exactly how you handle the input and output to it, including redirecting any and all of them directly to a log file if so desired. Be aware though that this is a much more complex mechanism with many pitfalls and tripping hazards.

More information on the standard streams can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).