# shell_execute(''youtube-dl') NOT WORKING .browser shows NULL. why?

Tags: php, youtube-dl

this is **try.php** file

```
<?
      echo shell_exec('youtube-dl https://yotube.com?xxxxxx');
?>
```

on command line
`php try.php` gives me the following

```
WARNING: Your copy of avconv is outdated and unable to properly mux separate video and audio files, youtube-dl will download single file media. Update avconv to version 10-0 or newer to fix this.
[youtube] 5Zq5wjkJ_Es: Downloading webpage
[youtube] 5Zq5wjkJ_Es: Extracting video information
[youtube] 5Zq5wjkJ_Es: Downloading DASH manifest
root@vps:/usr/bin#
```

but when i run on **web browser**

it shows 
[image]

Comment: Instead of going the upgrade approach for libav-tools, which several other packages depend on, let's use `--prefer-ffmpeg` after `youtube-dl`. This will tell the encoder to use `ffmpeg` as opposed to `avconv`. I've just tested it and it seems to work fine on an out of the box installation of Ubutu 14.04 TLS.

Comment: What's the question? Why the warning, or why no output in browser?

Comment: why no output in browser?

Comment: Why no output: Short tags, not enabling error reporting, not redirecting stderr `2>&1`, incorrect PATH setup, and youtube-dl does not send videos to stdout per default.

Comment: atleast it should echo something

Comment: It doesn't output anything because it's standard error, not standard output. Check out [PHP - How to get Shell errors echoed out to screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086572/php-how-to-get-shell-errors-echoed-out-to-screen)

Comment: var_dump() shows NULL. what should i do

Comment: Look at the `2>&1` that was appended to the command, it redirects standard error to standard output.

Comment: python: relocation error: python: symbol OpenSSL_add_all_digests, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara He is facing a Python related issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADD the following line to your shell_exec():

**LD_LIBRARY_PATH=''**

For Example snippet :

```
shell_exec("LD_LIBRARY_PATH='' youtube-dl https://yotube.com?xxxxxx");
```

Its a python problem. Even i had the same problem.

It will fix it