# php run command line and pipe std err to variable

Tags: php, command-line-interface, stderr

I am trying to figure out how to run a command line program within php and output both stout and stderr to a variable. All the examples either output the command line directly to the screen, or only output stdout for example

```
$data =  shell_exec('ls -sdlfkjwer');
```

will output the following directly to the screen and not store anything in $data

```
ls: invalid option -- 'j'
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

And the following will store the output in $data

```
$data =  shell_exec('ls -la');
```

because it is going to std out since there is no error. So the question is how can I route the std error to a variable as well when running command line programs from php?

This question does not answer my question because I am trying to do the exact OPPOSITE. I am trying to get it to a variable.
[PHP - How to get Shell errors echoed out to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086572/php-how-to-get-shell-errors-echoed-out-to-screen)

Thank you

Comment: I don't think you can route it to a separate variable, shell_exec just isn't built that way. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php - check the comments for some other ways to go about it

Comment: sure my question is to find any way to do it. I have also looked at exec function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I was able to find a solution. You need to set up a native process to configure the pipes.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr is a file to write to
);
$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('ls -lasdfsdfwefwekj', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);


/*fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
*/
fclose($pipes[0]);

echo "stdout=".stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
echo "stderr=".stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);

$return_value = proc_close($process);

echo "command returned $return_value\n";
```